# ASUS Laptop hard to turn on

Tags: asus-laptop

I have a problem with my **ASUS K42JP**, it is so hard to turn on that I need to get the back cover and let good ventilation to get in.

**Information/Insights**

• When I turn it on, there are times my fan won't turn on but after few minutes, it will start to run.

• There are also times that my fan turn off in the middle of me using the laptop

• I am facing these problems even using a CPU Cooler

What is possibly the problem of my laptop?

Comment: So all the issues are related to the fan?

Comment: I think so sir, is it possible my fan is clogged with dust?

Comment: Take your computer to a local qualified hardware technician.

Comment: @music2myear i would love to sir however as of this moment, i dont know who i can entrust my laptop

Comment: What do you mean the laptop is hard to turn on? Everything you describe about the fan sounds normal. The fan doesn’t run unless it needs to.

Comment: @Appleoddity I mean, when I turn it on, the power light turns on but the monitor stays black and sometimes the fan is not running. There are also times that even if the fan is running, the monitor still stays black. What I always do is get the back cover and wait for couple of minutes for the laptop to turn on.